# How to supress user actions on a ListBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, controls, mouseevent

Suppose we have a control (e.g. ListBox) and need to lock it from mouse clicks and keyboard actions. Of course, there is a standard property `Enabled`, but it causes appearance change, undesirable in my case.

I have found a simple solution using Windows API, see below. Suprisingly I haven't found a similar question exactly for my task so let me share this obvious solution with the community.

Any additions and comments are appreciated. In case someone will propose more appropriate/shorter/nicer answer.

Comment: Thank you, @MickyD, I agree with you and made some corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Windows API to lock our control from user actions.

First we should find out what standard WinAPI messages will be supressed while posting to the control. In my particular case of ListBox control I have chosen `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_SETFOCUS` messages ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown)), to lock both mouse and keyboard button presses and prevent my control from focusing.

Second we create a derived control class based on the `ListBox`, in the same namespace for convenience:

```
public class LockableListbox : ListBox
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }

    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (Locked)
            switch (m.Msg)
            {                
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                case WM_SETFOCUS:
                    return;
            }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Here the standard `WndProc` method of the control is overridden to stop chosen messages from posting depending on `Lock` flag state.

Third we just change `ListBox` to `LockableListBox` in our Form class designer part where it is required.

Now our modified ListBox will be protected from user actions (mouse clicks, keyboard actions and focusing) when the `Lock` property is set.

Comment: I wonder, is `[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]` line useful?

Comment: Well, I'm asking for the community until I found some info and answer myself.

Comment: You should have: `[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]` or `[SecurityCritical, SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]` (on WndProc). But it's not required here (on the override). It depends on where you work :)

Comment: No problem. +1 nethertheless

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi! I just saw it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=netcore-3.1) and then used in my example.

Comment: When you start black-listing messages, you are looking for troubles. What about right button events? Or cut/paste? I would suggest to disable that control and change the visual effects by handling `WM_CTLCOLOR` message.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion @VladFeinstein. Luckily those events you have mentioned look like having no effect on ListBox. Could you please give some code with `WM_CTLCOLOR` message handling?

Comment: Hi @AlexL, thanks for sharing the solution and you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT, I'll try this option, I have never heard of it before.